# HtmlUnit turn off page error tracing

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am using HtmlUnit to get some info from various web pages and when running the application it writes all page errors, CSS errors, script errors, from those pages. Can I shut that off? Thanks!

Comment: You mean it's all output to the console?   Do you have a log4j config file, most or all of it can be disabled via that.

Comment: right, ouput to the console.I am not sure about the log4j file?? where is that located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a file called "log4j.properties" in the root of your source code (i.e. where your "com" or "net" or what have you folders are) with this in it:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN,stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %c [%p] - %m%n 

log4j.category.com=NONE
log4j.category.com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript=NONE
```

You can then experiment the lines like the last two to turn logging on or off for various packages.   `log4j.category.com=NONE` should take care of pretty much ALL of it.